# How to configure WCF services to work through HTTPS without HTTP binding?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, web-config

I have configured my WCF services to work with SSL but it works ONLY if the HTTP binding exists in the IIS Web Site. When the HTTP binding not exists and exists only HTTPS binding  I get the following error:

> The HttpGetEnabled property of
>   ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true
>   and the HttpGetUrl property is a
>   relative address, but there is no http
>   base address.  Either supply an http
>   base address or set HttpGetUrl to an
>   absolute address.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what this exactly means "it works ONLY if the HTTP binding exists" ? Thanks... I am facing the same issue in my wcf.. WCf works fine one server but not on the other.. :(

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Modify your configuration this way:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior> <!-- behavior can have name (must have name in WCF 3.x) -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. But it only happens in few servers.. Services hosted one server is working fine and other server is throwing the error mentioned in question.. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you need to use mexHTTPSBinding unstead of mexHTTPBinding

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Comment: This isn't the cause of the OP's problem, but is true if you define the metadata endpoint as it needs to be available over `https`.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

Since you set httpGetEnabled to true, you need to provide a http address. And HTTP binding is a way to provide address. So if you remove it, you need to find another way to provide address.
Following are two ways to provide addresses.

HttpGetUrl :

```
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="[your service address]" />
```

HTTP base address:

```
 <host>
    <baseAddresses>
       <add baseAddress="[your service address]" />
    </baseAddresses>
 </host>
```