# 400 bad request WCF wsHttpBinding over Https

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating a WCF service and exposing couple of end point. One is basicHttpBinding and another is wsHttpBinding. Once I publish this to ISS basicHttpBinding end point is working fine but wsHttpEndPoint is throwing error 400.

There are so many posts about 400 error with WCF like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137294/wshttpbinding-over-https-causes-error-400-bad-request) but I cant resolve my issue.

Here is my configuration:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WsPlainBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="WcfService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding"
      contract="WcfService.IService" />
    <endpoint address="wshttp"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsPlainBinding"
contract="WcfService.IService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I am using the address from the wsdl generated from the service which is hosted in IIS. Still I cannot reach the end point from Visual Studio using Add Service Reference or from browser.

Comment: Turns out that both end points are working fine. i am trying to see each end point in the browser which is not supported and after adding reference it works fine once i pass the binding name for the client.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS go to manage Website->Advance settings and edit enable protocol. Add ,https.
Hope this helps

Comment: Https is already enabled. One end point is working fine which is on Https itself.