# Configuring a WCF service (Web.config) - HttpsGetEnabled, HttpsGetUrl

Tags: wcf, iis-7, web-config

I am trying to deploy a Silverlight with WCF Service to a hosting. Basically, I have the same problem as this guy:
[How to configure WCF services to work through HTTPS without HTTP binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863590/how-to-configure-wcf-services-to-work-through-https-without-http-binding)
Except the solutions don't work for me.

//edit: I've been pasting it wrong, but it still doesn't work.

I have tried Ladislav Mrnka's answer - changed this in the Web.config file:

```
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

The dreaded error still appears when I navigate to the .svc file on the server:

```
The HttpsGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the
HttpsGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no https base address.
Either supply an https base address or set HttpsGetUrl to an absolute address.
```

Comment: If your service is .NET 4, then have you checked if the app pool is set to use .NET 4?

Comment: The hosting should support up to .NET 4. Originally, I had the target framework set as 4.5, but this should work.

Comment: Is your <serviceBehaviors> tag closed? From your config sample it seems that it is not.

Comment: yeah I've been pasting it in the wrong place. Now it should be all correct, I just changed the httpGetEnabled and httpsGetEnabled in the proper place (it's already in the config file). But I still get the error. Should I perhaps specify the HttpsGetUrl somewhere? Where?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Now it should be all correct, I just changed the httpGetEnabled and
>   httpsGetEnabled in the proper place (it's already in the config file).
>   But I still get the error. Should I perhaps specify the HttpsGetUrl
>   somewhere? Where?

Yes, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx).

Should be:

```
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="NewBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" 
     httpsGetUrl="https://myComputerName/myEndpoint" />
  </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Hah! Upon uploading the config file for the bazillionth time, the .svc seems to be working! The application using it is still not working (there's an exception I can't access), but that's for a different question. For now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened because the setting is logically wrong. If you enable the httpsGetEnabled means, you allow clients to retrieve metadata via https. And if you don't provide a URL about https, how can clients retrieve metadata from https. So the error message alert you to provide a URL.

```
Either supply an https base address or set HttpsGetUrl to an absolute address.
```

You have three options.

1. Provide httpsGetUrl as other answers showed above
2. Binding an address via IIS

[image: Bindings]
[image: Site Bindings]

(if you are still developing in visual studio then you only need to degug with SSL Enabled mode )
[image: SSL Enabled]

3. Set httpsGetEnabled to false

Answer (score 0):

In configuration, under behaviour where you have set httpsGetEnabled="true",
Set httpsGetUrl="https://UserSystemName/EndPointName" too and problem resolved.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https:///UserSystemName/EndPointName"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```