# Exposing RESTful WCF service over HTTPS

Tags: web-services, rest, wcf, security, ssl

I've poked around dozens of blogs and SO questions and still can't get this to work.  I can load my service over HTTP, but I get the following error over HTTPS:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding secureWeb. Registered base address schemes are [https].

I'm hosting locally in IIS under an SSL site that works for several other apps already.  Here is the config that I am trying to get working; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="secureWeb">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <services>
    <service name="Example.TestService">
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingName="secureWeb" bindingNamespace="http://example.com/services"
                behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
                contract="Example.ITestService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    <serviceActivations>
      <add relativeAddress="Test.svc" service="Example.TestService" factory="Example.Common.ServiceModel.Activation.FlatWsdlServiceHostFactory" />
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: try something like this post where you specify httpsGetUrl:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127624/configuring-a-wcf-service-web-config-httpsgetenabled-httpsgeturl

Comment: @SQLDBA:  I added `httpsGetUrl="https://localhost/ExampleService/Test.svc"` to the `serviceMetadata` node, but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to everything else already said, I think you should have `bindingConfiguration="secureWeb"` instead of `bindingName="secureWeb"` 
(e.g. `<endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureWeb"...`)

Comment: Oh.. my.. god.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on a review of your WCF configuration, I think the issue may be related to the service metadata configuration. The configuration seems to specify that the metadata is available via http and https, but the endpoints only contain bindings for secure https (secureWeb).

In the following line, change the httpGetEnabled value from true to false.

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

Note: The [Creating a WCF RESTful Service And Secure It Using HTTPS Over SSL](http://www.allenconway.net/2012/05/creating-wcf-restful-service-and-secure.html) blog post mentions changing the service metadata options toward the end:

> ```
> <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
> ```
>
> Lastly, we need to update the metadata publishing endpoint to use
>   HTTPS as well:

Comment: I changed the httpGetEnabled to false, but no change.  (Well, I can't get the WSDL over HTTP anymore, but it doesn't change the HTTPS behavior.)

Comment: does the issue involve "hosting" the service (if so, what is the error in the WCF Trace file) or "calling" the service?

Comment: Hosting the service - it's giving me the error when I pull it up in a browser, not trying to make a call.  I'll set up tracing and see if there's more information.

Comment: Also, pulling it up over HTTP now gives `The HttpsGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpsGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no https base address.  Either supply an https base address or set HttpsGetUrl to an absolute address.`  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: The same error is what comes up in the trace.  `Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoing with binding secureWeb.  Registered base address schemes are [https].`

Comment: How are the IIS web site/directory bindings setup (http and/or https with SSL certificate provided)?

Comment: The same codebase is under two different Sites, which is how I can check HTTP vs HTTPS.  The HTTPS Site has SSL certificate provided and goes over 443.  The HTTP Site does not and goes over 80.